# pentaho integration with mysql-5.X

Tags: mysql, pentaho

When I was trying to replace the `hsqldb` with the mysql-5.X I get the following error with quartz error failed to initialize:-

```
Pentaho Initialization Exception
```

The following errors were detected
One or more system listeners failed. These are set in the systemListeners.xml.

```
   PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzSystemListener
```

Please see the server console for more details on each error detected.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the quartz scripts which setup the quartz db? they are provided in the solution repository.

Otherwise pastebin the full log, it's impossible to tell without more info. suspect somewhere you'll either have a authentication issue, or no mysql driver in your classpath.

For a clear guide on how to do this, follow here:

http://www.prashantraju.com/2010/12/pentaho-3-7-with-mysql-postgresql-oracle-and-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

I also received the error message

> PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 – Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler.QuartzSystemListener

when trying to bring up the service. I found this solution after searching a few different threads:

Remove commented out portion of these properties (or copy and paste from here, and modify as necessary) in `quartz.properties` (located in `pentaho-solutions/system/quartz`):

```
org.quartz.dataSource.quartz.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartz.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.quartz.user = pentaho_user
org.quartz.dataSource.quartz.password = password
org.quartz.dataSource.quartz.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.quartz.validationQuery= select 1
```

Also comment out the JNDI Url:

```
#org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.jndiURL = Quartz
```

Comment: I have the same problem

Pentaho Initialization Exception

The following errors were detected One or more system listeners failed. These are set in the systemListeners.xml. org.pentaho.platform.api.engine.PentahoSystemException: PentahoSystem.ERROR_0014 - Error while trying to execute startup sequence for org.pentaho.platform.scheduler2.quartz.EmbeddedQuartzSystemListener

The Catalina log https://www.dropbox.com/s/knpuu6nazwa8p0g/catalina.out?dl=0

The Pentaho log file https://www.dropbox.com/s/fz99afs9ov0pnfs/pentaho.log?dl=0

Please help me! Thanks in advance